# making vim autoclose {} tags adds a space

Tags: tags

I added a few lines to my .vimrc to autoclose tags like
`[]`, `""`, `''`, `()`
these all work fine but somehow the autoclosing of `{}` adds a space in between them and I have no idea how this comes.

```
"auto complete brackets
33 inoremap { {}<Esc>i                                                                                                                          
34 inoremap [ []<Esc>i
35 inoremap ( ()<Esc>i
36 inoremap " ""<Esc>i
37 inoremap ' ''<Esc>i
```

Anyone has an idea? Ask if you think it's handy for me to post the rest of my `.vimrc`

Thanks!

Comment: I add this line for in my `.vimrc` `inoremap \begin{document} \begin{document}<CR>\end{document}<Esc>O`, but doesn't work. where is the error in this line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that it comes from a trailing space at the end of the line 33 of your `.vimrc`. If a space is present after the last `i` character of your line, vim will interpret it literally and add it between your curly brackets.

Also you might be interested in the [auto-pair](https://github.com/jiangmiao/auto-pairs) plugin: it automatically insert matching characters and it also handle smarly the deletion of those characters.